# 2NF decompositions are dependency preserving?

Tags: database-theory

I have read that 1NF, 2NF and 3NF decompositions are lossless and dependency-preserving.

Consider this example on a relation $R(A,B,C,D)$ with functional dependencies set as $FD =${ $AB \rightarrow CD, A \rightarrow C, BC \rightarrow D$ }

Here when we do 2NF decomposition we get $R_{1}(A,C)$ with $FD =${$A \rightarrow C$}  and $R_{2}(A,B,D)$ with $FD =${$AB \rightarrow D$}

The functional dependency $BC \rightarrow D$ is lost when we join but we know that 2NF is dependency preserving so why is it that we are unable to preserve the original FD?

Comment: "I have read that 1NF, 2NF and 3NF decompositions are lossless and dependency-preserving." No, you haven't. Please quote an actual claim from a published competent source.

Comment: Your "I have these FDs" doesn't make sense. "These are all the FDs that hold"?--Not possible. "These are all the non-trivial FDs that hold"?--Not possible. "These are some FDs that hold"?--Question can't be answered. Find out what a *cover* is & what the exact conditions are to apply a particular definition/rule/algorithm. To determine CKs & NFs we must be given FDs that form a cover. Sometimes a minimal/irreducible cover. And the set of all attributes must be given. [See this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53386492/3404097)

Answer (score -1):

Although you decomposed the table using the dependency that violates 2NF $(A\rightarrow C)$, the new tables are in BCNF, and decomposition to BCNF is not always dependency preserving.